# Getting permission denied error when calling Google cloud function from Cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to invoke Google cloud function which is Http triggered by cloud scheduler.
But whenever I try to run cloud scheduler it always says permission denied error

```
 httpRequest: {
  status: 403   
 }
 insertId: "14igacagbanzk3b"  
 jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"   
  jobName: "projects/***********/locations/europe-west1/jobs/twilio-cloud-scheduler"   
  status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"   
  targetType: "HTTP"   
  url: "https://europe-west1-********.cloudfunctions.net/function-2"   
 }
 logName: "projects/*******/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-09-20T15:11:13.240092790Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id: "***********"    
   location: "europe-west1"    
   project_id: "**********"    
  }
  type: "cloud_scheduler_job"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-09-20T15:11:13.240092790Z"  
}
```

Solutions I tried -

1. Tried putting Google cloud function in the same region as the App engine as suggested by some users.
2. Gave access to Google provided cloud scheduler sa **service-********@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iamaccount.gserviceaccount.com** owner role and Cloud Functions Admin role
3. My cloud function has ingress setting of Allow all traffic.

My cloud scheduler only works when I run below command

*gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding cloud-function  --member="allUsers"  --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Cloud Scheduler page, you have to add a service account to use to call the private Cloud Function. In the Cloud Scheduler set up, you have to

- Click on `SHOW MORE` on the bottom
- Select `Add OIDC token` in the `Auth Header` section
- Add a service account email in the service account email for the Scheduler
- Fill in the Audience with the same base URL as the Cloud Functions (the URL provided when you deployed it)

*The service account email for the Scheduler must be granted with the role cloudfunctions.invoker*

[image]

Comment: If you're working with the 2nd gen Cloud Functions, you should grant the caller Service Account the `roles/run.invoker` role instead of `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker`.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was related to restricted ingress setting for the cloud function. I set it to 'allow internal traffic only', but that allows only traffic from services using VPC, whereas Cloud Scheduler doesn't as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings) explanation:

> Internal-only HTTP functions can only be invoked by HTTP requests that are created within a VPC network, such as those from Kubernetes Engine, Compute Engine, or the App Engine Flexible Environment. This means that events created by or routed through Pub/Sub, Eventarc, Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Tasks and Workflows cannot trigger these functions.

So the proper way to do it is:

- set the ingress to 'all traffic'
- remove the permission for allUsers with role Cloud Function Invoker
- add the permission for created service account with role Cloud Function Invoker
- or just set that permission globally for the service account in IAM console(you could do that when creating service account as well)

Answer (score 3):

If you tried all of the above (which should be the first things to look at, such as Add OIDC token, giving your service account role Cloud Function Invoker and/or Cloud Run Invoker (for 2nd gen functions) etc.), please also check the following:

For me the only thing that fixed this, was adding the following google internal service account to IAM:
`service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
And give this internal service account the following role:
`Cloud Scheduler Service Agent`

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth

And especially for this case:
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#add

Comment: Everything worked until the moment I pressed the SECURITY ACCESS button that it showed in my Clour Run console. I did the necessary "Secret Manager Secret Accessor" as well as what you described.... - but it still does not work. Two questions: 1. What is the Cloud Scheduler Target URL? (i.e. can it still be the GCR-APi's xyz.run.app URL or no longer ?   And question 2: Can GCR-API and GCR-Scheduler run on two different regions ? Desperate help needed on this....

Comment: [Have a working solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440191/permission-denied-error-when-calling-google-cloud-run-api-from-cloud-scheduler/77441235#77441235)