# GCP Cloud Scheduler AND Cloud Functions are not able to call a Cloud Function without Owner IAM permissions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm using Google Cloud Platform to host my infrastructure. It basically consists of a Cloud Scheduler and about 3 or 5 Cloud Functions chained together. I'm not using Workflow, each function simply calls the next one.

It works like this:
Cloud Scheduler > Control (Cloud Function 2gen) > Login (Cloud Function 2gen) >
and so on...

I created one Service Account (SA) for the Cloud Scheduler and Control Function, e.g. "schedule-control@sa.com" to use OIDC Auth;
and one SA only for the Login Function, e.g. "login@sa.com";

I gave those SAs, the following permissions.

For schedule-control@sa.com: `Cloud Run Invoker (the only one that docs explicitly says it's needed), Cloud Scheduler Admin, Cloud Scheduler Job Runner, Cloud Scheduler Service Agent, Firestore Service Agent, Service Account Token Creator and OWNER`;

For login@sa.com: `Cloud Pub/Sub Service Agent, Cloud Run Admin, Cloud Scheduler Service Agent, Firestore Service Agent and OWNER`.

The Control Function, only controls which accounts will be used to login. And it uses google-auth-library to authenticate the call to the Login Function.

Ingress settings is set to `Allow all traffic` in all Functions.

My problem is: Everything works fine with OWNER permission. Whenever I remove OWNER permission from the SAs, I receive these errors:

For Control Function:

```
    GET 500 699B 151ms Google-Cloud-Scheduler https://function-url.app

    {
    errorGroups: [1]
    insertId: "65aae2e2000698ca2697d4b5"
    labels: {2}
    logName: "projects/project/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
    receiveTimestamp: "2024-01-19T21:00:18.518683682Z"
    resource: {2}
    severity: "ERROR"
    textPayload: "Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
        at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
        at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
        at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
        at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:99:78
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)"
    timestamp: "2024-01-19T21:00:18.432330Z"
    }
```

For Login Function:

```
Error 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I followed these tutorials for Cloud Scheduler calls to Cloud Functions [first](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler); [second](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#create_a_scheduler_job_with_authentication). And [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) tutorial for Cloud Function calls to another Cloud Functions.

I also tried to:

- delete the Cloud Scheduler, the Cloud Function and the SA to create in different orders (SA before Cloud Function and vice-versa);
- use the default scheduler-SA on Cloud Scheduler and Control Function;
- Remove scheduler-SA aswell as disable and re-enable the Cloud Scheduler API, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709656/15077313);
- manually add Cloud Scheduler SA, as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#add).

I tried pretty much everything that is suggested in these questions: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235853/how-to-invoke-cloud-function-from-cloud-scheduler-with-authentication/61238251#61238251); [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055422/cannot-invoke-google-cloud-function-from-gcp-scheduler) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980844/getting-permission-denied-error-when-calling-google-cloud-function-from-cloud-sc).

P.S: I thought about creating one question for Cloud Functions invocation through Cloud Scheduler and another one for Cloud Functions invocation through Cloud Functions. But it's the same problem for both scenarios and I really think it's something messed up with permissions.

UPDATES:

- I just tried what Guillaume suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849219/15077313) and it still doesn't work.
- As John Hanley asked:

1. This is the service accounts (I redacted project_id):
   [image: service accounts]
2. Scheduler-account being used in Scheduler Job:
   [image: scheduler]
   [image]
3. Cloud Run permissions
   [image]
4. Cloud Functions permissions
   [image]
5. Cloud Run Logs
   [image]
   [image]
6. Cloud Functions Logs
   [image]
7. Scheduler Job Logs:

```json
{
  "insertId": "166kycqfeg8q73",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "jobName": "projects/project/locations/europe-west6/jobs/control-light",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
    "url": "https://europe-west8-project_id.cloudfunctions.net/control",
    "targetType": "HTTP",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 500
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "control-light",
      "project_id": "project_id",
      "location": "europe-west6"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-01-29T13:00:18.544518124Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/project/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-01-29T13:00:18.544518124Z"
}
```

Comment: We need the principal and roles that you assigned. Show the commands or a good description from the Google Cloud Console GUI. Most likely you are not assigning the correct IAM roles to the IAM principal (service account) making the call. What does Cloud Logging indicate for each error?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry my late response @John Hanley.
I'm not sure if I got what you need specifically, but I added a few prints of Service Accounts, Scheduler configuration, cloud Function and cloud Run permissions, aswell as the errors I'm getting at each product (cloud Scheduler, Functions and Run) extracted from Logs Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud Functions 2nd generation, you must grant Cloud Functions Invoker AND Cloud Run invoker role on the SA. (Cloud Functions 2nd gen is a "wrapper" of Cloud Run which is behind the scene)

The owner role grant you the 2, but it's a bad practice, prefer the 2 mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added Cloud Functions Invoker and gave time to propagate the alteration but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add the audience? If so, what's the value of it?

Comment: Sorry my late response. Yes, I tried editing my scheduler a few times, with and without audience. As it is 2nd gen function, I simply copied the same URL that invokes the function. I read that if the Audience field is blank, it uses URL by default.

Comment: Can you go to Cloud Run and copy the Cloud Run URL for your function. And then add this URL as audience.

Comment: Thank you again, @guillaume. I just did and unfortunately didn't work. The errors are exactly the same, Permission Denied. By the way, I just added a few updates to the original question as John Hanley asked. Maybe you can find it helpful.